# adding pojos as process variable in jbpm 5

Tags: jbpm

I am using jbpm 5.2 to execute business processes whitch need sometimes to store pojo variables into the process context. Everything works just fine and i can get the pojos back from the session. but if the server restarts, i cant get my variables anymore and i have an exception saying "could not reload variable". I think the problem is related to class loading and the jbpm engine can't find classes or interfaces for the pojo it tries to recover and fails with a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not reload variable.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Come on guys, i really need your help. I tried to put all classes referenced by my variable pojo in the classpath of my human task server but no success

Comment: Do you have a test that we could use to reproduce this? Have you by any chance tried this on the latest release to see if this is something that might have been fixed already?

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace of the exception?